# I want to arrange and print words entered by the user in different combinations? Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, permutation

Example:

input:

Number of words user want to enter : 3

Word no. 1: cat

Word no. 2: rat

Word no. 3: dog

output:

cat rat dog

cat dog rat

rat cat dog

rat dog cat

dog cat rat

dog rat cat

something like this.

Here is the code of another program, where I arranged letters in different combinations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char character_swap(char*, char*);
void permutation(char*, int, int);

int main()
{
 char str[99];
 
 printf("Enter a string to find its permutations.\n");
 scanf("%s",str);
 
 system("clear");

 int n = strlen(str);
 permutation(str, 0, n-1);

 return 0;
}

char character_swap(char *x, char *y)
{
 char temp;

 temp = *x;
 *x = *y;
 *y = temp;
}

void permutation(char *a, int l, int r)
{
 if (l == r)
 printf("%s\n", a);

 else
 for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
 {
 character_swap((a+l), (a+i));
 permutation(a, l+1, r);
 character_swap((a+l), (a+i));
 }
}
```

Can anybody tell me, how can I do the same thing with words?

Comment: What happens when someone enters a duplicate string? Just the same? You will probably have to accept `char **` (pointer to a char -> string) if you want to do it this way.

Comment: I will remove the duplicate strings/words from the input data. And can you please, how ` char **` will help me?. As I am new to C and there are things that I still don't know. And the problems that I faced during the creation of the program were I was facing trouble in swapping words and taking a multi-dimensional array as a function parameter by using pointers.

Comment: Hi Aayush - first, realize that strings in C are merely arrays of characters (with a null character at the end to denote the end of the string). So, in order to *sort* a bunch of strings, you first need to *store* the strings. This is most easily accomplished with a 2-dimensional array (which you'll want to read up on). Once you have the strings stored, you can modify your character swap if you want, but if all you're interested is the output, you can accomplish this more easily by just re-ordering numbers that correspond to the rows of the array (matrix). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a good job separating the `permutation` implementation from the `main` interface, such that this can this be done fairly easily. First, there are a few inconsistencies,

- In `character_swap`, one has declare return type `char`, but never
  return anything; must be `void`. It's used only in this file, so it should be `static`; this will avoid namespace conflicts let the compiler perform more aggressive optimizations. It also prevents prototype warnings as long as it is declared above.
- `int` is not really the right type for working with indices; `size_t` is more appropriate.
- It's a little awkward to explain that `permutation` is always going to be called with 0 index as it's second parameter. It's better to drop that and fill it in later, I have accepted the size in `character_permutation`, which calls `character_permutation_r`.

I have generalized the type from `char` to `type` using a `typedef`; I just replaced `char` by `type`. It would be simpler and clearer to replace `type` by equivalent `char *`, but in the next iteration, we are going to replace it with a totally opaque type; a `typedef` is warranted it because it keeps them all the type information together.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* This is part of the interface. */

void character_array_output(const char *a, const size_t size) {
 (void)size; /* Don't use the size -- it's null-terminated. */
 printf("%s\n", a);
}

/* This is the implementation. */

typedef char type;

typedef void (*character_array_action)(const type *, size_t);

static character_array_action character_print = &character_array_output;

static void character_swap(type *x, type *y)
{
 type temp;

 temp = *x;
 *x = *y;
 *y = temp;
}

static void character_permutation_r(type *a, const size_t l, const size_t r)
{
 if (l == r)
  character_print(a, r + 1);

 else
 for (size_t i = l; i <= r; i++)
 {
  character_swap((a+l), (a+i));
  character_permutation_r(a, l+1, r);
  character_swap((a+l), (a+i));
 }
}

static void character_permutation(type *a, const size_t size) {
 if(size == 0) return;
 else character_permutation_r(a, 0, size - 1);
}

/* This is part of the interface. */

int main(void)
{
 char str[99];

 printf("Enter a string to find its permutations.\n");
 scanf("%98s", str);

 character_permutation(str, strlen(str));

 return 0;
}
```

For your question, `type` is `char`, and you want it to be `char *`, you just replace it with `typedef char *type`. However, a generalization to any assignable type is possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* This is the implementation.
 `name` satisfies `C` naming conventions when mangled
 `nametype` is an assignable type
 `array_output` is a function satisfying `name##_array_action` */

#define DEFINE_PERMUTATION(name, nametype, array_output) \
typedef nametype name##type; \
\
typedef void (*name##_array_action)(const name##type *, size_t); \
\
static name##_array_action name##_array_print = &array_output; \
\
static void name##_swap(name##type *x, name##type *y) \
{ \
 name##type temp; \
\
 temp = *x; \
 *x = *y; \
 *y = temp; \
} \
\
static void name##_permutation_r(name##type *a, const size_t l, const size_t r) \
{ \
 if (l == r) \
  name##_array_print(a, r + 1); \
\
 else\
 for (size_t i = l; i <= r; i++)\
 { \
 name##_swap((a+l), (a+i)); \
 name##_permutation_r(a, l+1, r); \
 name##_swap((a+l), (a+i)); \
 } \
} \
\
static void name##_permutation(name##type *a, size_t size) { \
    if(size == 0) return; \
    else name##_permutation_r(a, 0, size - 1); \
}

/* This is the interface. */

void character_array_output(const char *a, const size_t a_size) {
    (void)a_size;
    printf("%s\n", a);
}

void string_array_output(char *const a[], const size_t a_size) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
        printf("%s%s", i ? ", " : "", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void integer_array_output(const int *a, const size_t a_size) {
    printf("{");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
        printf("%s%d", i ? ", " : "", a[i]);
    printf("}\n");
}

typedef int (*operation)(int);
static int value;
void operation_array_output(const operation *a, const size_t a_size) {
    printf("{");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
        printf("%s%d", i ? ", " : "", value = a[i](value));
    printf("}\n");
}

DEFINE_PERMUTATION(character, char, character_array_output)
DEFINE_PERMUTATION(string, char *, string_array_output)
DEFINE_PERMUTATION(integer, int, integer_array_output)
DEFINE_PERMUTATION(operation, operation, operation_array_output)

#include <math.h>
static int square_n(const int n) { return n * n; }
static int sqrt_n(const int n) { return sqrtl(n); }
static int double_n(const int n) { return 2 * n; }

int main(void)
{
 char str[] = "abc";
 character_permutation(str, strlen(str));

 char *strings[] = { "cat", "rat", "dog" };
 string_permutation(strings, sizeof strings / sizeof *strings);

 int numbers[] = { 42, 99, 1, 0 };
 integer_permutation(numbers, sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers);

 operation ops[] = { &square_n, &sqrt_n, &double_n };
 value = 1;
 operation_permutation(ops, sizeof ops / sizeof *ops);
 value = 5;
 operation_permutation(ops, sizeof ops / sizeof *ops);

 return 0;
}
```